# Check array for unique values and output csv

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to loop through an Access query, find all the unique values from a field (in this case called UtilityDunsNumber), put them into an array and then run another query for each DunsNumber in that array and output a CSV file with all the records from that new query, then loop back through to create a file for each DunsNumber.

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim records() As DAO.Recordset
    Dim duns() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim fs As String

    fs = "C:\TestECI\IN_572_COMPANY_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & "_814EN01_"

    Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qry_RequestECI")

    'loop through records, get list of unique DUNS numbers
    'get unique duns
    For Each Record In records
        If IsInArray(Record.UtilityDunsNumber, duns) Then
            continue
        Else
            ReDim Preserve duns(1 To UBound(duns) + 1) As String
            ' add value on the end of the array
            arr(UBound(arr)) = Record.UtilityDunsNumber
        End If
    Next

    For Each UtilityDunsNumber In duns
        Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qry_RequestECI WHERE UtilityDunsNumber =" & dun)
        i = 2000
        fs = fs & i & ".csv"
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , records, fs, True
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

It is failing here:

```
Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qry_RequestECI")
```

with the error

> "Can't assign to array"

Comment: What's the question?  What does this code produce, or where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry my bad, when compiling it stops at `Set records = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qry_RequestECI")` with the error "Can't assign to array"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim records() As DAO.Recordset
```

Here you're declaring an *array* of recordsets...

```
Dim records As DAO.Recordset
```

Is probably what you want.

Comment: yes that's correct. I'm trying to put the results of the query into an array so it can separate the results by the dunsnumber field and move into the next loop where it can output the csv files

Comment: `OpenRecordset` returns a single Recordset object, not an array of Recordsets.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simplification that may or may not help.  To get the list of Duns numbers, you can use

```
set DunsRS=db.openrecordset "select UtilityDunsNumber from qry_RequestECI group by UtilityDunsNumber"
```

And then you can loop through the list with

```
DunsRS.movefirst
do while not DunsRS.eof
 dun = DunsRS.fields("UtilityDunsNumber").value
 ... 
 ...
 DunsRS.movenext
 Loop
```

This might be enough to fix the problem - not sure without trying it.

Comment: just curious - did this help?